Solution of the "reciprocal of the heat equation"?
I was playing around with the heat equation in one dimension and tried to guess what the solution to homogenous boundary conditions and a sine wave as initial condition on the interval $0<x<\pi$ would look like for the slightly different equation :
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}}$$
Can anyone help me use a method to find an analytic solution ? I have tried to visualize the solution nummerically on Matlab but it looks to be very unstable and after a very short time the real look of the solution is messed by the nummerical limitations of using a finite difference method (forward in time and centered in space). I was wondering if there is anyone who can give me some reference on any document that analyses this equation. Thank you!

Assuming a half sine wave for $u(x,0)$, doesn't the initial concavity of $0$ at $u(0,0)$ and $u(\pi,0)$ imply step functions for $u$ at $t=0$ at $u(0,0)$ and  $u(\pi,0)$?

try fourier to x?
